# Splitting large column in table to another table of smaller columns MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, where-clause, clause

I've been pulling my hair out trying to split a large column in a table (1.7 million rows) down into 24 much smaller columns in a different table.

The table from is:
"postcodes" which contains the column to be split "postcode" and an auto increment "id" column

& the table to is:
"postcodes_spit" which contains 24 columns called "postcode**n**" (insert 1-24 in **n**)   ;-)

I can INSERT in the first of 24 columns fine:

```
INSERT INTO postcodes_split (postcodes1)
SELECT postcode 
FROM postcodes 
WHERE (id <= 72974);
```

but subsequent INSERTS of course don't start from row 0 in the other columns.

I tried to do UPDATE instead but I've got the syntax wrong and I can't seem to make it right:

```
UPDATE postcodes_split 
SET postcodes2 = postcode FROM postcodes 
WHERE id FROM postcodes BETWEEN 72975 AND 145948
```

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: This really isn't very clear at all and I'm not even certain what the question is. Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: It appears that you are trying to convert a well-designed SQL table into an badly-designed one.  Why are you doing this?

Comment: Refer to this question may be it solve your problem


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692852/mysql-turn-one-long-table-column-into-table-with-multiple-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an untested idea, which I would only suggest for a one-time operation like this:

```
 UPDATE postcodes_split pcs, postcodes pc
 SET pcs.postcodes2 = pc.postcode
 WHERE pcs.id = pc.id - 72974
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Please stop and reconsider what you are doing.  Is this really necessary?  Data stored in a wide format like this is the bane of SQL programmers everywhere.  It is not the right way to do it!

However, assuming you continue anyway:

Each `INSERT` statement creates a new row.  So, the best approach is to insert all 24 columns at once in one command. Do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO postcodes_split (postcodes1,postcodes2,postcodes3,...)
    SELECT p1.postcode, p2.postcode, p3.postcode...
         FROM postcodes p1 WHERE (id <= 72974)
         join postcodes p2 on p2.id = p1.id + 72974
         join postcodes p3 on p3.id = p1.id + 145948
         ...
```

Your exact math may vary, depending on whether id is 0-based or 1-based.

Again, don't do this (but I suppose your boss is probably telling you to do it; in which case, have fun!).